# Be hunger or be hungry?

Tags: grammaticality

If I have to give advice to my student, which of the following 2 sentences is correct?

1. Be hunger to learn new things.
2. Be hungry to learn new things.

Please advise.

Comment: You cannot "be hunger"; "be hungry" works fine.

Comment: I think this might have been a more fitting question for [ell.se]. Cheng, I hope you'll check it out.

Comment: "Be hunger" might be used in a metaphorical sense (often with an emphasis on "be").  It's not uncommon to say something like "be the truth" or "be the river" to imply becoming "one with" an inanimate concept or entity.  "Be hunger" would imply making an effort to understand hunger (presumably in others).

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Presumably because the question shows no research, displays an obvious lack of knowledge of basic English grammar (like knowing the difference between a noun and an adjective), can be easily answered by a simple dictionary lookup, and is thus blatantly off-topic. There is ample reason to downvote this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say 2.

According to Cambridge Dictionary:

Hunger:

> **noun**: the **feeling** you have when you need to eat

Hungry:

> **adjective**: wanting or needing food

Usually, verb-to-be is followed by an adjective, or article + noun. The context requires the student to have instead of to be a need of knowledge, therefore the answer is 2.

P.S.

> As proposed by @Jeeped, we can also "have a hunger for new things".

Comment: You could metaphorically *'have a hunger for new things'*.

Comment: agree, will add to ans later

Comment: why the downvote, please?

Answer (score 1):

In English, students are said to ***be thirsty*** for knowledge;

> **thirst for knowledge**
>   curiosity that motivates investigation and study
>
> - *He spent much of the day in the city’s library, where his thirst for knowledge first developed.*
> - *His home is a reflection of his insatiable **thirst for knowledge** and to continually discover and inhabit a sense of wonder*.

Source: Vocabulary.com

The following link has some [synonyms](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/thirst%20for%20knowledge) for "thirst of knowledge"

Comment: I agree that _thirst_ works, but [hunger](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hunger+for+learning%2Cthirsty+for+learning%2Chunger+to+learn%2Cthirst+to+learn&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) works, also. Either one can be used for any sense of yearning.

Comment: why the downvote?